# Concatenate Column Values Row by Row Dynamically

Tags: vba, excel

My code concatenates the values of the columns of the first row of table "Data" and writes the result in table "Insert" cell A1.

The error is that the concatenation result of next row is added at the end of the first result in table "Insert" A1 and so on. The results should be written in table "Insert" in column A row by row too.

What is wrong with my code?

```
Sub InsertStatementRow()
Dim x As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim ColMax As Integer
Dim i As Long

    Sheets("Data").Select

        ColMax = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    row = 1
    Do While Cells(row, "A").Value <> ""

        With Worksheets("Data")
        i = 1
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, ColMax))
        End With

        For Each cel In rng

            x = x & cel.Value

        Next

        Sheets("Insert").Cells(i, 1).Value = x

    row = row + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i is being set as "1" each time the Do While loop begins, so the rng variable will always refer to row 1 of the Data worksheet. It's also copying to row 1 on the Insert worksheet. Change the i to row and it should work:

```
Do While Cells(row, "A").Value <> ""
    With Worksheets("Data")
        Set rng = Range(.Cells(row, 1), .Cells(row, ColMax))
    End With

    x = ""

    For Each cel In rng

        x = x & cel.Value

    Next

    Sheets("Insert").Cells(row, 1).Value = x

row = row + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

you set

```
i=1
```

before

```
Set rng = Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, ColMax))
```

but you seem to bee working with variable `row`. So delete/comment the line `i=1` and change `Set rng`

```
Set rng = Range(.Cells(row, 1), .Cells(row, ColMax))
```

hope it solves your problem.